# Writing into xlsx file - newline causes problems

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to write some text into `xlsx` file using `openpyxl` module. It works good until I try to write text (`text = '\n'.join(list_of_sentences)`).

It seems that it writes it correctly (no error is raised) but when I try to open the file, openoffice freezes. The file is somehow corrupted.

I've tried already `text = r'\n'.join(list_of_sentences)` but it did not help.

Maybe it is because of this Warning:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\styleable.py:111: UserWarning: Use formatting objects such as font directly
  warn("Use formatting objects such as font directly")
```

Could you give me an advice how to do it correctly?

EDIT - THE CODE:

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        i+=1

        splitted = line.strip('\n').split('::')
        name = splitted[0]
        text = splitted[1].split('***')
        text_xlsx = '\n'.join(text)
        # text_xlsx.replace('_x000D_','\n')
        worksheet.cell('B{}'.format(i)).style.alignment.wrap_text = True
        worksheet.cell('B{}'.format(i)).value = text_xlsx
```

Example of the text_xlsx:

```
'dir\\dir\\dir\\dir\\dir\\.file_name.pl-pl::\xef\xbb\xbf<p><strong class="title">&euro;this</strong></p>***<p><span class="text">Please add Peter\'s account &euro;1!.<br /> <a target="_blank" href="some url">click to redirect</a></span></p>\n'
```

Comment: I just tried writing to an xls file using openpyxl with `\n` between text in a cell, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Same here, no problems with newlines. Are you sure the problem is because of newlines?

Comment: The warning is entirely unrelated. It is just advising you to update your code to the new styles API.

Comment: Guys, I've added my code there so you can check where could be the problem. I have to say that it's a text from pl-pl files and contains text, html etc.

Comment: Then the problem could be definitely with the kind of text there in the file.

Comment: I've added an example of the text.

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha Maybe it is the problem but I've added classes.add(text.__class__) into the loop and it returns set([<type 'str'>]) so it is probably just pure text so I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: I dont see `classes.add(text.__class__)`

Comment: @Milan: first try with replacing f by a list of strings and tell us if it works.

Comment: @EricLevieil It works, no problem. With another file it works too. I think it is because it thinks that there are special characters inside those texts. / \ tags, hyperlinks etc. So what I have to probably do is to tell the openpyxl that it is a pure text.